# Using cookies on a site to redirect based on location - Googlebot crawling

Tags: googlebot, cookie, geolocation

I've recently began working on a `Wordpress` site that uses `cookies` to redirect a user to the appropriate regional page based on their location with `geolocation`.

One thing I've noticed is that this might have a detrimental effect on my site as I don't think `spiders` can crawl the site fully as they can't store cookies??

Am I right in assuming that Googlebot does not store cookies and if so then have I completley gone about implementing my site in the wrong manner?

I've done a bit of research on this and have not seen a definitive answer. I've come here to see if the community would have more information.

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have alternate hreflang tags in place across your pages? Are all of your pages allowed to robots for indexing?

Comment: Yes I do I've got these in the header.php file

Comment: Then I don't understand what difference cookies would make.

Comment: My worry was if a spider comes to the site and I assign it a cookie based on its region and redirect it that it wouldn't maintain this cookie so it would effectively end up in a loop going from / to /us over and over

Comment: How do you know which version to redirect a new user to, since they won't have *any* cookie yet...?

Comment: As soon as a user arrives on my site I detect their location via geolocation and store this in a cookie I immediately then redirect them to the appropriate homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you're right that search engines don't typically read or store cookies. However this shouldn't in itself cause problems for you.

You haven't said which, but you're using either the user's IP address or browser language setting to determine which regional page to redirect to. Presumably, there's also a default region which is used if your conditions aren't met. You then set a cookie so the site "remembers" where to send a repeat visitor.

Most search engines crawl from a single geographic location and don't send `Accept-Language` HTTP headers, so can't necessarily "see" how these conditional redirects work. As a result, we need to **ensure that all versions are crawlable** and provide information (like `hreflang`) which identifies the intended audiences for our content.

Google have recently tried to address this with ["locale aware crawling"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=en), whereby they issue `Accept-Language` headers and crawl from multiple, geographically diverse IP addresses. However, we don't know much more detail than that, so we can't make any safe assumptions about how this works in practice.

So:

1. Ensure that search engines can fully access all regional pages (i.e., crawlable links between them)
2. Use `hreflang` – this is currently supported by Google and Yandex
3. Use `lang` attribute of `<html>` with ISO language or language-country pairs to indicate target for other search engines (Bing, etc.), e.g., `<html lang="en-gb">`

Comment: That's a brilliant answer and very helpful thanks very much :)